Flutter App Error in in integrating SQLite
I am integrating SQLite in the Flutter app in Android Studio but it gives me an error -
Error is -
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sqflite_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\amank\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process D:\android studio files 13\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\amank.gradle\caches\transforms-3\fb247f22548bfd545efa0cbc10d96775\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\amank.gradle\caches\transforms-3\fb247f22548bfd545efa0cbc10d96775\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I will try every possible thing, but it is not working, so I expect a digital solution for this error.
